# Using Quantum Teleportation in a way to have the effect of matter teleportation

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-information, quantum-teleportation

So, I understand that quantum teleportation is the transfer of a quantum state from one particle or system of particles and its correlations to another receiving system consisting of particle(s). Can't this be used in a way to achieve teleportation as depicted in sci-fi?

You start out with a translationally entangled particle pair (position and momentum are correlated) as described by this paper:
http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v61/i5/e052104

Now according to these papers, you can theoretically teleport the position and momentum information of particle. Atomic teleportation of the external degrees of freedom, (Their position and momentum)

http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v49/i2/p1473_1

http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v86/i14/p3180_1

http://iopscience.iop.org/0295-5075/75/6/847

Firstly, I need someone to help me understand **exactly what is being teleported in regards to the papers I've listed**. I understand completely the discrete case of quantum teleportation with spin or polarization, I'm not asking for that.

This is what I know:

1) Start out with a translationally entangled pair.
2) Interact an "input" particle with one of the pairs.
3) Make a measurement of the input particle with one of the pairs' position and momentum.
(This is the step I don't really understand) But I know that this is analogous to the Bell state measurement in discrete quantum teleportation that is widely described everywhere.
4) This result is communicated to the other laboratory where appropriate "shifts" of position and momenta are done to the entangled pair just like in the discrete case again.

So, if position and momentum information is teleported, then does this mean that if the input particle was propagating in the X-direction like a wave-packet, then after teleportation, the receiving particle will now move in the X-direction relative to its original position? This is quite confusing to me.

I want to understand this because I want to ask the trillion dollar question, "What if you are to replace the input particle with a input MOLECULE?"

For a diatomic molecule, its simply two atoms of the same type. According to this wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals

I know there are vibrational states in molecules which ARE essentially position and momenta information right?

If we are to set up TWO translationally entangled pairs of atoms of the same type...
And have them simultaneously interact with the molecule in step 3), *then can't we do the appropriate SHIFTS of the entangled pairs of atoms to make them turn into the input molecule?!*

So, the overall effect is that if you start out with H2 in Lab A, and had a translationally entangled pair for each atom, then you'll end up with H2 in Lab B after teleportation which is exactly what we want if we want to stick close to the sci-fi sense.

If what I am saying makes sense, then can't this be in principle be extrapolated to larger molecules and eventually cells, and organs, to an entire human? I know that this is a large jump...

However, what I'm trying to say is that according to this kinda scheme I'm asking about, its sticking to real physics, and its essentially accomplishing teleportation in the sense people know about. Do I make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is a short, quick response.

There is an old [IBM webpage](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/view_project.php?id=2862) which discusses the differences between classical and quantum teleportation which I am happy to see has migrated over the years.  Essentially, quantum teleportation allows for a complete unknown arbitrary state to be transferred from one object to another, as long as the original object's original state is destroyed ([no cloning theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem)).  This article differentiates this from a classical "facsimile" type of data transmission that we are familiar with. What is important in both cases is that the [conservation of energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy) must be preserved, and the [speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) obeyed.

You could, in principle take a system in some quantum state, entangle it with some third system made of entangled pairs (while simultaneously destroying the original system and classically transmitting the measurement information) then recover that system at some other location by allowing the other entangled particle to interact with some raw material at that location.  However, during this entire situation you will not dematerialize a system and rematerialize it in some other location if it would violate conservation of energy or the speed of light.

Comment: I'm not looking for the usual definition of quantum teleportation, ... talking about the discrete case or the conceptual difference between classical and quantum... I already understand that! I'm looking for a specific answer I've emphasized about. Also, I'm not talking about dematerializing and rematerializing at all. I'm not violating the uncertainty principle, conservation of energy, nor am I violating the speed of light. I'm just applying the current quantum teleportation protocol of the continuous variables case in to teleporting the position/momenta information of a molecule.

Comment: Here is a [nice article on the subject](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/blog/2012/02/tangling-with-teleportation/).  There have been various discussions on this topic off and on for several years.  In principle its possible, in reality it is unlikely we would ever have sufficient scalability to quantum teleport a state as complicated as a human. I believe there are some papers floating around give crude estimates, but I am not aware of rigorous calculations.